# get the comment element text using cherrio selector

Tags: jquery, cheerio

This jQuery like selector "cheerio" tries to get the comments from the comments nodes in an html page.
$ is the cheerio object. 
How can it do it? Thanks

```
console.log($('*').contents().length); //reports back more than 1000


$('*').contents().filter(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 8) {

    //the following gives null for every node found
    console.log($(this).html());

    //the following gives blank for every node found
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of a comment isn't either HTML (`.innerHTML`) or a value (`.value`), it's the `.nodeValue`. jQuery doesn't provide a function to get that for you and I doubt Cheerio does either, but you don't need one: Just use `this.nodeValue`:

```
$('*').contents().filter(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 8) {
    console.log(this.nodeValue);
  }
});
```

(I've used `filter` there because your example did, but if you're not using the return value of `filter`, `each` makes more sense.)

Here's a DOM example, but presumably Cheerio will work similarly:

```js
$("*").contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 8) {
    console.log(this.nodeValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Comment 1 -->
<!-- Comment 2 -->
<!-- Comment 3 -->
<!-- Comment 4 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sir, can I search for specific comment?